# Website Error each time rebuild and upload to Server : Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: access-violation

My Server:
Window Server 2008 R2
IIS 7.5

Each time I edit code locally then upload it to the server, it gets an error:

```
Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.  Event time: 7/4/2016 7:53:10 AM  Event time (UTC): 7/4/2016 12:53:10 AM  Event ID: d5bd5d3e12a14d1eabe43f91b5d3c7ef  Event sequence: 721307 Event occurrence: 704  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/30824/ROOT-4-131120555752900745 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\vhosts\xxxxxxxxx\httpdocs\ 
    Machine name: COLO1298    Process information: 
    Process ID: 6932 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: COLO1298\IWAM_plesk(default)    Exception information: 
    Exception type: AccessViolationException 
    Exception message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.    Request information: 
    Request URL: http://xxxxxxxxx.com.vn/publish/form/RegisterForm.aspx 
    Request path: /publish/form/RegisterForm.aspx 
    User host address: 171.254.38.251 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: COLO1298\IWAM_plesk(default)    Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 55 
    Thread account name: COLO1298\IWAM_plesk(default) 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:


at Microsoft.Win32.NativeMethods.CreateProcess(String lpApplicationName, StringBuilder lpCommandLine, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, Boolean bInheritHandles, Int32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, String lpCurrentDirectory, STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation)   
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)  
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)  
at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters options, String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String arguments, String& outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue, String trueArgs)    
at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)   
 at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)    at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)    
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()    
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()    
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)    
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)   
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)    
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)    
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)    
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)    
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

When I restart IIS, it's OK again.

I don't think the source code has a problem because when I upload it to another server, this doesn't happen.

Comment: Is the other server has the same version of IIS i.e. Window Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 ? Try restarting your machine ...

Comment: The other server has the same version IIS and Windows Server 2008 R2.
Each times occurs error, I just need restart IIS, Website is running correct.
But this error just happen after editing source code, some times happe, some time not.